# Passing Scope Through $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work and show me how to make it work? I've tried creating a namespace and IIFEs functions but I cannot seem to get it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert (hi);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var hi = "hello"
});
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hi = "hello"
});
```

You are creating a variable named `hi` that is local to that callback function.  It is simply not accessible outside that function.  This is a feature of the language.

You can declare the variable at a higher scope like this:

```
var hi;
$(document).ready(function() {
  hi = "hello"
});
```

And, then the value of that variable will be available outside the scope, but you will not necessarily know when it gets the proper value because you won't know when the `$(document).ready()` callback is called unless you put your code inside that callback.

---

It really makes little sense to try to share a variable between two calls to `$(document).ready()`.  It would make much more sense to just put the code inside the same `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hi = "hello"
  alert (hi);
});
```

---

**Not Really Recommended**

If you were going to try to share a variable between two calls to `$(document).ready()` (something I don't really recommend because it makes your code somewhat fragile), it can be done.  Callbacks to `$(document).ready()` will be called in the order they are attached so you will have to order things appropriately:

```
var hi;
$(document).ready(function() {
  hi = "hello"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert (hi);
});
```

This will make sure that the first `$(document).ready()` callback that sets the value of `hi` will be called first before the second one where you try to use the value.